# How to prevent manual deletion of individual items from Chrome Browsing History?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extensions, history

I am monitoring my ward's usage of Internet on my device. I would like it to be all transparent that is saved in history and such that it can't be deleted by my ward. Avoiding access entirely to the device is not an option as nowadays we have got online classes in schools- so files,assignments,meets etc all require usage.

I have disabled the incognito mode in chrome. I want to disable the option provided for deleting individual items in Chrome browsing history. Is there a way?

Or is there a way to password protect my chrome browsing history without locking chrome itself ?

**I have tried:**

1. Click the Windows button and search for Registry Editor
2. Right-click on it and select Run as administrator.
3. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Policies > Google > Chrome`
4. Right-click anywhere on the right side, and create a new DWORD (32-bit) Value and name it AllowDeletingBrowserHistory with no spaces.
5. Double-click on it, and change the Value data to 0
6. Click OK, and close the chrome browser if it is open.

[Prevent history deletion on Google Chrome - Superuser StackExchange](https://superuser.com/questions/110675/prevent-history-deletion-on-google-chrome) : This link has a method given in its best answer but I am not that tech-savvy, so don't exactly understand the process nor have the reputation to comment and find out.

This disables the Clear ALL browsing history option but does not remove the scope for preventing individual items from deletion. Is there any way - any extension or trick for this or even for password protecting only my Chrome Browsing History?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to protect from your own accidental deletion or do others have access to the computer? For yourself, you can always grab mistakes back from your backup. For others, don't let them use your account.

Comment: @Tetsujin I am monitoring my ward's usage on my device. I have disabled incognito mode and thus want to secure my browser history from deletion. There are essential files and school online classes meetings that are to be done daily. So, avoiding access is not an option however I might wish to.

Comment: That reasoning should ideally be added to your question, because knowing it may be the opportunity for someone to think of a workaround, rather than a direct answer.